# How to retrieve a client secret from UAA

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I am using UAA as an OAuth2 provider. I created a client using `/oauth/client` API endpoint with a `client_secret` that I have forgotten. I tried the list clients API endpoint but it did not provide me the client secret in the response.

How can I find the client's secret?